# With Doctype HTML, there is unwanted extra space at bottom of table cell

Tags: html, html-table

How to remove unwanted space below textarea within table cell? Thx.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<table border=1>

<tr><td class=property_big>Comments</td><td></td><td><textarea 
class=boxwidth cols=20 rows=3 name=description></textarea></td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` and `float:left;` in your `CSS` to the `boxwidth class` of the `<textarea>` like this:

```css
.boxwidth
{
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td class="property_big">Comments</td>
  <td></td>
  <td><textarea class="boxwidth" cols="20" rows="4" name="description"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Or, you could write the `style` directly to the element in `HTML` like this:

```
<td><textarea class="boxwidth" cols="20" rows="4" name="description" style="position:relative; float:left;"></textarea></td>
```